# Raspberry Pi piezoelectric compatibility

Tags: raspberry-pi, piezo

I am looking to control two piezoelectric actuators using a Raspberry Pi. I am looking at these [piezoelectrics](https://www.physikinstrumente.com/en/products/piezoceramic-actuators/stack-actuators/p-286-p-288-p-289-disk-translators-101752/). I have read on the Internet that it is difficult/impossible to use piezoelectric actuators with a Raspberry Pi due to the piezoelectric's necessary voltage input. Will this be doable? I can be more specific about the project if need be. If you have any links to someone who has done a project like this before I would greatly appreciate them.

I realize that piezoelectric actuators may not be the best idea because of the voltage demand.

I am looking for some type of actuator that can move at a fairly high frequency (>10-20 Hz) along one axis with a travel distance of around 0.1 - 0.5 mm. Any suggestions would be welcome. I have been looking at linear actuators but the ones I have seen seem to move too slowly for my application.

Comment: 1,000V to travel 0.5mm (max)? You're not going to get very far by just plugging one into a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @MickSharpe If I connect to an external voltage source could that work? I guess 1000V is pretty large for a hobbyist application.

Comment: I would look for another type of actuator. Perhaps you could edit your question and tell us what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

It will work with a raspberry pi, but your movement range will be almost zero. From the datasheet:

> P286XX: 100 μm range, 0 V to -750 V
>   P288.00: 50 μm range, 0 V to -1 kV
>   P289.20: 200 μm range, 0 V to -1 kV

With a voltage range of 0 V to -3.3 V from the Raspberry pi, you will get a range of motion of 200 μm / 1 kV * 3.3 V = 660 nm, assuming that you use the most sensitive one (P289.20). If that's really enough for your application then yes, it will work.

You probably want to add a 3.3 V transient suppression diode in parallel with the actuator so you don't murder the Raspberry pi with a multi-kV spike when someone accidentally hits the actuator.

If you actually want the full range of motion, you need a 1 kV signal to drive it. You could buy an off the shelf piezo amplifier to do this, e.g. [Trek 2210](http://www.trekinc.com/products/2210.asp). Another option would be to roll your own design, possibly even using a fully integrated piezo amplifier chip which you can design into your circuitry do this, e.g. [DRV2700](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv2700.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

0.5 mm range of movement suggests a loudspeaker actuator. It will meet your speed requirement. You will need a driver circuit to provide enough current. I would suggest that two (ubiquitous) LM386-type amplifiers in a bridge configuration would work:
[image]

There are also many Class-D speaker drivers that can extend their frequency response down to DC, and are designed to accept a low-voltage drive, like the 5v used by Ras-Pi.
You don't need the speaker cone, just its spider voice-coil mount. For a small speaker (such as that used inside older PC's) the magnet/spider assembly is a few cm dia. Voice coil resistance is about 6 ohms. The spider mounting of the voice coil keeps the coil centered and allows movement in and out for currents in one direction or the other.
[image: example loudspeaker actuator]

Comment: I think piezo actuators can create much more force.